# Deploying created Helm chart on remote Kubernetes cluster from local machine

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Currently I created Helm chart for my Kubernetes resource and trying to deploy on my remote Kubernetes cluster from my local machine where I configured the helm client and kubectl. I created the Helm chart by using the following command,

```
helm create my-chart
```

And after creating I edited the image values in my-chart/values.yaml. Now I need to deploy this docker image on my remote Kubernetes cluster

**My confusion**

1. Here my confusion is that, when I deploying do I only need to use 'helm install' command? It will deploy on my cluster?
2. If I need to access the service, how I can access the result from cluster? Do I need to set cluster IP or node IP?

I am new to Helm chart with Kubernetes.

Comment: Have you tried `helm upgrade`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To upgrade/install a helm chart, you can try running `helm upgrade --install CHART_NAME --values values.yaml`. This behaves like upsert and deletes any existing resources that need to be modified and creates new resources that reflect your `values.yaml`
2. Accessing the service is dependent on how your Helm Chart exposes the service. If your Helm Chart created a ClusterIP-type service, then you can access it within the cluster. If it's exposed as a nodePort/LoadBalancer/Ingress, then you can access it externally. To test ClusterIP services, you can use `kubectl port-forward svc/your-service-name 8000:8000` (or some port number mapping applicable to your service). With the port forwarding, you can access the service on `localhost:8000`.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. I used NodePort.  So how i can access the service ? I have cluster with one master and 3 nodes. So which nodeIP can use ? How I know about the nodeIP where It deployed ? Since i have 3 node as worker.

Comment: If you used NodeIP, then you have to check which node your pod was scheduled to. You can run `kubectl describe pod pod-name` and figure out which node it was scheduled to. Then run the describe command on the node to figure out its external IP.